# Unit test a controller that calls another controller through the Startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net web api project, and i want to unit test an action in a controller.

This action calls another static method in a `ServiceManager` class which calls another action in another `controllerApi`! a `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method from the startup class has to be called to properly set a couple properties in the `ServiceManager` in order for the action to return something !

The following diagram illustrate that:

[image: diagram]

What i want to unit test is to make sure that when `actionFoo` is called, than `actionBoo` is also called. I don't want to do an integration test, and i don't want to moq the whole configuration so that the unit test will be useless.

What is the right approach to test these kind of scenarios ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds totally wrong and smells of bad code design. It would be better if you could supply the important bits of code from ControllerA, ControllerB and the ServiceManager. Also you prob shouldn't be calling one controller from another, sounds like you're doing something wrong there. Another thing that it sounds like is that you're not injecting ServiceManager instance into your controllers. Lastly if you're unit testing your controllers you've prob got too much logic in then IMHO

Comment: Hi @matt_lethargic, thanks for your reply :)
I am sorry, in order to make the question simpler i might rolled out some important details. ControllerA is part of an Api that monitors other Apis in other servers (so in reality i have ControllerB in another server providing CPU usage, memory ... and a couple of other controllers as well in other servers), i get from what you are saying that i probably shouldn't go as far as testing the whole food chain ans stick with testing each api by it self ?

Comment: If Controller A is in a different API to Controller B then this is definitely an integration test even if both api's are in the same solution. If your 'unit' being tested is the controller then you should consider the controller as being a black box and testing the outputs vs the inputs so to speak.

Comment: Yea that makes sense, you may want turning your comments into an answer and i will accept it ;), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the OP, testing a controller that calls another API is an integration test, so not a unit test as you talked about. Testing each controller in isolation is usually the domain of a unit test, mocking the dependencies and testing the outputs against the inputs.